# I draw some graph using JQplot. and now when i mouse over the individual bars in the bar graph in JQplot some values should be displayed

Tags: jquery

I draw some graph using JQplot. and now when i mouse over the individual bars in the bar graph some values should be displayed.. plz help

my graph is as follows...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var line1 = [['Content Of The Training', 2.2], ['Relavance Of Training To The Work Place', 3.5], ['Phase Of The Training', 3.2], 
  ['Session Met The Objectives Stated', 3.4], [' The Session Met My Exceptations', 3], 
  ['Overall Ratining On the Training', 3.6]];

  var plot1 = $.jqplot('graph1', [line1], {
    title: 'Rating On Training',
    series:[{renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer}],
    axesDefaults: {
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
        tickOptions: {
        fontFamily: 'Calibri',
          angle: -30,
          fontSize: '10pt'
        }
    },

    axes: {
      xaxis: {
        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
      }
    },
        canvasOverlay: {
      show: true,
      objects: [
        {horizontalLine: {
          name: 'pebbles',
          y: 2.5,
          lineWidth: 2,
          color: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
          shadow: true,
          lineCap: 'butt',
          xOffset: 0
        }},

      ]
    }
  });
});
```

for the plugins download jplot from the following link

http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jqplotDataMouseOver` event.

Docs here: http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/barTest.html

This example fills `#info` container with the information about the bar you clicked. You should be able to get mouse coordinates from the `ev` param and play with that.

```
$('#graph1').bind('jqplotDataMouseOver', 
     function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
                $('#info').html('series: ' + seriesIndex + ', point: ' + pointIndex + ', data: ' + data);
     }
);
```

Also you could take a look at this:
http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-highlighter-js.html

It shows how to enable the tooltip. I'm not sure if it works on all kinds of graphs.